# Why aren't my admob ads showing up?

Tags: android, admob

I have followed the documentation on how to add ads, however I seem to be missing something, because the sample app is working. The admob account is reporting that my application is requesting ads, I see the requests in logcat, but the ad is not showing up.

This is the code for onCreate:

```
this.adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.appLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest ad = new AdRequest();
ad.addTestDevice("DEVICE_ID");
this.adView.loadAd(ad);
```

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/appLayout"
     >

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/myListView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scrollbars="vertical" 
       >
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the AndroidManifest.XML:

I declared the 2 required persmissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

and the activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm attaching a logcat also

```
05-26 21:04:01.761: I/Ads(6186): adRequestUrlHtml: removed requestHtml also
05-26 21:04:02.171: I/Ads(6186): Received ad url: removed ad url from here
05-26 21:04:02.752: I/Ads(6186): onReceiveAd()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems, that I had also implemented onResume(). The whole ad loading should be done there if you have both onCreate and onResume implemented.

Answer (score 0):

it's because, your view is not visible, Your ListView us taking all the space. Kindly change that it will work.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I tried setting the listview height to 0px, so anything else would have space, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you put ad before adding listview ? and if it's visible than issue is with the listview.